# ios: how to populate mapview from .plist file

Tags: ios, objective-c, for-loop, mkmapview

Hello and Thanks for the help.

Is it possible to populate 10 mapview locations from a .plist file using a for loop ? If so how ?

my current code for my mapview is all hard coded.  I would like to improve upon this by pulling - Longitude, Latitude, Title, SubTitle - from a for loop if possible.  Thank You.

```
  ////
.....
                MKCoordinateRegion region3 = {{0.0,0.0}, {0.0,0.0}};

                region3.center.latitude = 33.45869;
                region3.center.longitude = -84.66931;
                region3.span.longitudeDelta = 0.01f;
                region3.span.latitudeDelta=0.01f;
                //  [mapview setRegion:region4 animated:YES];

                BandsMap *ann3 = [[BandsMap alloc]init];
                ann3.title = @"Indigo Bar & Lounge";
                ann3.subtitle = @"Let the good times roll";
                ann3.coordinate = region3.center;//

            //// 


                annoArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:ann1,ann2,ann3.....,nil];


                [mapView addAnnotations:annoArray];.......
```

Something like this I suppose but not quite sure how to finish

```
        for(NSDictionary *key in mapDataPlist)
            {
                    NSString *c = [key objectForKey:@"Title"];
                NSString *a = [key objectForKey:@"SubTitle"];
                NSString *lat = [key objectForKey:@"Latitude"];
                NSString *lon = [key objectForKey:@"Longitude"];

                CGFloat strFLat = (CGFloat)[lat floatValue];
                CGFloat strFLon = (CGFloat)[lon floatValue];

//////

?????

             }
```

Comment: Is your plots an array of dictionaries?

Comment: @Wain Yes they are.  The plist has a root of Array and Item 0 - 10 are Dictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just iterate over your plist array and use the code you have to create the regions from the extracted data. Then, instead of `annoArray` being an array you create at the end, make it a mutable array and add each item at the end of each loop iteration.

Answer (score 0):

```
[mapView setRegion:adjustedRegion animated:YES];
    mapView.mapType=MKMapTypeStandard;
    UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame] style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    tableView.dataSource = self;
    tableView.delegate = self;
    tableView.frame = CGRectMake(28, 60, 334, 649);
    [self.view addSubview:tableView];


    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:
                      @"CityList" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSMutableArray *cities = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    NSMutableArray *localCities= [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for (int i=0;i<[cities count];i++)
    {
    NSLog(@"%@",[[cities objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"cityNameKey"]);

        [localCities addObject:[[cities objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"cityNameKey"]];
    }


    locationArray= localCities;

    Annotation *annotation=[[Annotation alloc]init];
    annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(29.7631,-95.3631);
    annotation.color = [UIColor redColor];
    annotation.title=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Houston"];
    [mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
```